# For an HTTP OPTIONS request, is there any point in having a response body?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, cors

Currently if I respond to an options request, there is no need to send any response body that I know of, only headers to indicate what I will accept

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: example.com");

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: API-Key, Query-Sequence");
    header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Query-Sequence");

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS'){
        die;
    }
    //....
```

But would there ever be a case where the body would be used for something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.2):

> The response body, if any, SHOULD also include information about the
> communication options. The format for such a body is not defined by
> this specification, but might be defined by future extensions to HTTP.

You *can* include it, and if you do it should probably be a plain English description of the options that are allowed. There isn't much point in doing so though.